# Storing JavasScript settings locally

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

With HTML5 and local storage, can JavaScript be used to save the state of a web page?

For example, some sites have `increase font size` buttons that are most likely controlled with JS. How can the property be saved so that on a refresh the size stays the same? Or is this done without JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to use `localStorage`, unless you do not want the settings to persist upon new sessions (you would use `sessionStorage` in that case). If you have multiple settings, you can store a serialized representation of your settings.

E.g.

```
var settings = {
    fontSize: '11px',
    otherConfig: 'test'
};

localStorage.setItem('settings', JSON.stringify(settings));

//then you can retrieve it
settings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('settings'));

console.log(settings.fontSize); //11px
```

Note that if you want the settings to persist when users connects from multiple computers, you will have to use some server-side support.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is done with Javascript. You can use

- [**Cookies**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie)
- [**Sessionstorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage)

  This is a global object (`sessionStorage`) that maintains a storage area that's available for the duration of the page session. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated.
- [**Localstorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage)

  `localStorage` is the same as `sessionStorage` with same same-origin rules applied but it is persistent.

The better/easier ones are `sessionStorage` and `localStorage`. The problem is that they aren't supported by old browsers.

Instead, dealing with cookies can be a nightmare, but they work on old browsers too.

Comment: You cannot use `sessionStorage` as it will expire once the browser gets closed.

Comment: Which one is better, easier, and has more advantages?

Comment: cookies have the most browsersupport, but as cookies will be send back to the server with each request, they also have a lot of network overhead. Localstrorage is the best solution unless you need <IE8 support.

Comment: Cookies are also limited by size and count (i.e. you can only store a limited number of cookies with a limited size)

In your case size won't be a problem and you're not storing a lot of values so cookies will work

Answer (score 1):

Yes can save state to localStorage.

assume you have an object :

```
var settingsObj={

   pageClass:'bigFont',
   widgetSortOrder : [1,5,3,7]

}
```

You could save that whole object to one local storage key by stringifying the object. When page loads you would see if that key exists in localStorage and have your javascript do whatever it neds to with those settings

To stringify and store:

```
localStorage.setItem('mySettings', JSON.stringify(settingsObj) );
```

To retrieve from storage and convert to js object

```
var settings=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mySettings'));
```